# How to update OneToOneField using Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make an image upload through a REST API from a mobile client. I've managed to implement it using an multipart request to the REST endpoint, but when I try to update the image, the request is not handled correctly because of the constraints on the OneToOneField.

---

This is how I implemented the API:

**models.py**

```
class Hotel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False, blank=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False, blank=False)
    rating = models.FloatField()
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']


class HotelPhoto(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='hotel_photos', null=True)
    hotel = models.OneToOneField(Hotel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class HotelPhotoUpload(APIView):
    parser_classes = [FormParser, MultiPartParser]

    def post(self, request):
        photo_serializer = HotelPhotoSerializer(data=request.data,
                                                context={'request': request})

        if photo_serializer.is_valid():
            photo_serializer.save()

            return Response(photo_serializer.data,
                            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            logger.error(f'Error uploading image: {photo_serializer.errors}')
            return Response(photo_serializer.errors,
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class HotelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    photo = serializers.ImageField(source='hotelphoto.photo', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Hotel
        fields = ['url', 'id', 'name', 'address', 'rating', 'owner', 'photo']


class HotelPhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    photo_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = HotelPhoto
        fields = ['hotel', 'photo', 'photo_url']

    def get_photo_url(self, obj):
        return self.context['request'].build_absolute_uri(obj.photo.url)
```

---

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Error uploading image: {'hotel': [ErrorDetail(string='hotel photo with this hotel already exists.', code='unique')]}
Bad Request: /hotels/photo/upload/
```

I understand this is due to the constraint on the OneToOneField since I've have already uploaded a photo, but how should I do the request in order to just update the `HotelPhoto.photo` field?

**What I've tried**

- Implementing a put method on the `HotelPhotoUpload` view with `partial=True` on the serializer, but it gave the same error.
- I thought about overwriting the `validate` method on the serializer, but I don't know if I need to validate anything on the photo itself. I was hoping the framework would handle this for me.
- Thought about merging the `HotelPhoto` and `Hotel` models, but that would require a big refactor of other code.

---

**EDIT**:

I'm currently using django 3.0.2.
Following the answer by neferpitou, I've managed to get it working after these minor changes:

**serializers.py**

```
# Didn't change the HotelSerializer

class HotelPhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hotel = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
            many=False,
            queryset=Hotel.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = HotelPhoto
        fields = ['hotel', 'photo']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Instead of creating a new HotelPhoto instance
        # changed the photo field from the Hotel instance
        hotel = validated_data.get('hotel')
        photo = validated_data.get('photo')
        hotel.hotelphoto.photo.save(photo.name, photo)
        hotel.save()
        return hotel.hotelphoto
```

**views.py**

```
class HotelPhotoUpload(APIView):
    parser_classes = [FormParser, MultiPartParser]

    def post(self, request):
        # I'm already sending the hotel id on the POST request
        photo_serializer = HotelPhotoSerializer(data=request.data)
        if photo_serializer.is_valid():
            photo_serializer.save()

            return Response(photo_serializer.data,
                            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            logger.error(f'Error uploading image: {photo_serializer.errors}')
            return Response(photo_serializer.errors,
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

One thing that I forgot to mention is that I'm always sending a request (either POST or PUT) to the `hotels` endpoint (which uses the `HotelSerializer`) before uploading a photo. So I'm not expecting to have problems on the `photo/upload` endpoint due to an inexistent hotel.

**mobile client**

Unfortunaly can't post the Multipart POST request content because it's huge. But here is the client method implementation using Retrofit 2.5.0.

```
// Sends the hotel id and the entire content of the photo file.
@Multipart
@POST(UPLOAD_ENDPOINT)
fun uploadPhoto(@Part("hotel") hotelId: RequestBody,
                @Part photo: MultipartBody.Part) : Call<UploadResult>

companion object {
    const val UPLOAD_ENDPOINT = "hotels/photo/upload/"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Foreignkey` and `OneToOneField` can be serialized in the same manner.
Here is your
`views.py`

```
class HotelPhotoUpload(APIView):
    # parser_classes = [FormParser, MultiPartParser]

    def post(self, request):
        hotel = Hotel.objects.get(name=request.data.get('hotel'))
        request.data['hotel'] = hotel.id
        photo_serializer = HotelPhotoSerializer(data=request.data)
        # print(photo_serializer)
        if photo_serializer.is_valid():
            photo_serializer.save()
            return Response(photo_serializer.data,
                            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            # logger.error(f'Error uploading image: {photo_serializer.errors}')
            return Response(photo_serializer.errors,
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class HotelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Hotel
        fields = '__all__'


class HotelPhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hotel = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, queryset=Hotel.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = HotelPhoto
        fields = ['hotel', 'photo',]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        hotel_photo = HotelPhoto.objects.create(**validated_data)
        hotel_photo.save()
        return hotel_photo
```

I am confused why there are extra fields in your `HotelSerializer`, so I have trimmed it down. If you have specific use case for those feel free to modify in your code. And there are no primary key in your `Hotel` model, so it will create `id` field by default and I am assuming every `hotel name` in unique.

Postman request:

[image]

Hotel Data From Admin Section:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped. Now it's giving me an `IntegrityError` on `photo_serializer.save()`, but I believe I can work around that.

Comment: It worked after some minor changes to your answer. On the `create()` method instead of creating an `HotelPhoto` instance, I saved the image directly on the `Hotel` instance given by `validated_data.get('hotel')` using `hotel.hotelphoto.photo.save(photo.name, photo)`.

Comment: `Foreignkey` and `OneToOneField` can be really tricky with drf, there is also not much docs about it. Glad it was of some help at least :)

Comment: If it's not asking too much, could you adapt your answer with the changes I've made so that I can accept it? I don't want to accept it while it's partially working, but I also don't want to leave the question unanswered when it's already been solved.

Comment: I will but what Django version are you using?

Comment: and also if you can add the code which worked for you, it would be helpful. I am trying how a reverse relation worked, without creating a new instance of `HotelPhoto`. I am just curious and I would like to reproduce it on my system. Specially the view, serializer and the data for post request.